# setup.py install running egg_info error: [Errno 13] Permission denied regarless of install directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

I encountered a bug-like feature of setup.py where I am getting the Permission denied error regardless where I want to install the package without root privilege.

I have a toy python package with a few tiny files, and there is no problem of building it.  There is nothing special in the setup.py file.  I will list one or two of them.

```
setup (
   name='pmsi',
   entry_points={ 'console_scripts': [ 'pmsi = pmsi.pmsi:main', ] },
)


sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Gave me no problem at all.  I need to install this package to a particular place and have tried --user, --home, --prefix options; all gave me the same error message at the egg_info step.

```
python3 setup.py install --user
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

It appears that the install process always tries to copy the egg_info to some system place where I don't have permission to write.  I am not an expert on setup.py, there must be some default rule that I can overwrite either on the command line or setup.py.  Or should I always install to system place as root (that seems to be a bad choice, what if you want to test before a system install).

Comment: Now figured it out.  Because I run sudo before in the package directory and it created some directory with owner as root. Then I run as regular user I got permission issue. After sudo chown -R myuid:myuse *, the problem got resolved.  I was thinking in the wrong direction for almost one hour.

Comment: You can also use `--prefix` to install modules within a particular directory (eg. `python3 setup.py install --prefix=/path/to/install`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the prefix option. Experimented that too. I was misled by my own mistake. Most of the time, programmer's problem was caused by something other than what we think.  I read the setup.py documents very carefully for more than a hours. Kind of like getting a ticket and go to traffic school.  Some punishment and a little benefit.

Comment: @KeminZhou In which directory did you run `sudo chown -R myuid:myuse *`?

Comment: @CameronHudson something like: ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages.  You can always try to find the package with find: find $HOME "your code file name"

Comment: @KeminZhou make your comment into an answer and accept it (after cool-down period). And I'd upvote that too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this particular difficulty is because I run sudo before in the package directory and it created some directories owned by root. Afterwards, I run as a regular user and got permission issues. The fix is ownership change.

```
cd ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages
sudo chown -R myuid:mygroup *
```

After the above action, the problem was resolved. The actual python lib dir may be different for different situation.

Comment: I ran into this problem when sharing a package over NFS with different users.

The first user to install a package from a directory will create a <mypackage>.egg_info/ directory within the source directory and that may not be accessible to other users.as it was created 755 (although pip 22.3.1 creates it with group write and it also sets the group sticky bit)

Anyway - for those stumbling upon this problem this directory may be the issue.